# backbone persistent login - login removed on browser quit

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js, authentication

I am working on a backbone application that hooks into  RESTful API. One problem I having at the moment, is that a user can be logged, they can then close there browser, reopen it go to my application and be logged out. Is is possible to make a login persistent until the user explicitly actions a logout?

My login process is token based, so I thought it would be as simple as loggin the access token in a cookie, and then checking for that cookie, but once the browser is closed the cookie seems to get deleted (not something I have come across before).

I run this check on a page load, to check if the user is logged in,

`if(!App.Session.authenticated()) 
     return App.Routes.Application.navigate('/login', {trigger:true});`

This fires this method,

```
 authenticated: function() {

        return Boolean(this.get("access_token"));

  },
```

However the on browser startup the Session model where this method is always empty, and so are the cookies, how can I make the logins persistent? I love how Trello works, I never seems to have to login.

It is worth noting the rest of the my authentication process is working great, user get tokens, when the token runs they get news ones, up until the user shuts down their browser!

Comment: The browser does persist your cookies unless it is malformed (are you setting the expires= part properly and not on private browsing?). You can set a client cookie straight from the server in the response to the login request, thereafter the cookie is passed in all the comms so the server is able to authenticate requests.

Comment: @DominicTobiasI had not set an expire! thanks. make that answer if you want.

Comment: sure I will claim this glory ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be missing the `expires=` part of the cookie.

> You can also add an expiry date (in UTC time). By default, the cookie is deleted when the browser is closed:
>
> document.cookie="username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC";

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp